Example Windows 3.11 286 protected mode program - how long did Win 3.1 286 protected mode last?
This ancient program to sort a text file was used as a test case for Windows 3.1 286 protected mode. Since the 64 KB segments can't overlap, it read the file 63 KB per 64KB "chunk" and would handle split records by appending the split part in the second chunk to the partial record in the first chunk. An array of pointers to records was created while reading, then sorted and a new sorted file written. It uses the popular at the time Windows | Hungarian naming conventions.
Question: how long did this period of Windows 3.1 286 protected mode last? I recall SCO (Santa Cruz Operations) taking over Xenix from Microsoft, and they had both 286 and 386 versions of Xenix, but that wasn't Windows. I wrote some device drivers for both versions of Xenix.
Link to source + build files + a test text file (IN.TXT, 12500 lines, 80 characters (+cr +lf) digits of pi). JSRT.MAK was generated by the compiler, I use JSRT.NMK with nmake to do the actual build.
https://rcgldr.net/code/jsrt.zip
The source code:
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      jsrt.c          Jeff's Sort Demo                                */
/*                                                                      */
/*      Jeff Reid       01OCT93  19:00                                  */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      abbreviations for name prefixes                                 */
/*                                                                      */
/*      a       array of ...                                            */
/*      cb      count of bytes in ...                                   */
/*      dw      double word (unsigned)                                  */
/*      hf      handle to file                                          */
/*      hl      handle to local memory                                  */
/*      hg      handle to global (huge) memory                          */
/*      lp      long (_far) ptr to ...                                  */
/*      p       pointer to ...                                          */
/*      sz      string terminated by zero                               */
/*      w       word (unsigned)                                         */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      Sorts text files: each record ends in CR(0x0d), LF(0x0a).       */
/*      After reading file converts CR/LF to HI/LO # bytes in record.   */
/*      Assumes 'HI' part is less than any text character in record,    */
/*      so the shorter of two otherwise equal records will be           */
/*      considered less than the other.                                 */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      equates                                                         */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _AHINCR  0x0008                 /* huge ptr selector incr */

#define ENDCR    0x0d                   /* cr at end of record */
#define ENDLF    0x0a                   /* lr at end of record */
#define MAXRECSZ 0x0200u                /* max record size */
#define CHUNKSZ  0xfc00u                /* < (0x10000u - MAXRECSZ) */

#define XP_SEG(fp) (((unsigned *)&(fp))[1])
#define XP_OFF(fp) (((unsigned *)&(fp))[0])

enum eState{                            /* states */
    SINIT,                              /* init */
    SNOPARMS,                           /* no parameters */
    SBADPARMS,                          /* bad parameters */
    SOKPARMS,                           /* parameters are ok */
    SSORT};                             /* sorting started */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      data                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

static BYTE szCmdLine[80];              /* copy of cmd line params */
static BYTE *pszSrcName;                /* source file name */
static BYTE *pszDstName;                /* dest   file name */

static HFILE    hfSrc;                  /* handle to source file */
static HFILE    hfDst;                  /* handle to dest file */
static DWORD    dwSrc;                  /* size of source file */
static WORD     cbSrc;                  /* for _lRead */
static WORD     cbDst;                  /* for _lWrite */
static WORD     wNumRec;                /* # records in file */

static DWORD    dwTicker;               /* Tick count for delay */

static BYTE     fState;                 /* program state flag */

static HLOCAL   hlMem;                  /* local mem handle */
static BYTE *pLclBase;                  /* local mem ptr */

static HGLOBAL  hgMem;                  /* global mem handle */
static void _far *lpMemBase;            /* global mem ptr */

static BYTE _far **palpRec;             /* ptr to array of ptrs to recs */

static char *pszState[5] =              /* strings for state */
   {"Initializing",
    "No Parameters Specified",
    "Bad Parameters Specified",
    "Sorting",
    "Sorting Done"};

static BYTE aucCRLF[2] = {ENDCR, ENDLF}; /* end of record */

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      code                                                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
long FAR PASCAL _export WndProc(HWND, UINT, UINT, LONG);

static void DoCmdLine(void);            /* process parameters */
static void DoSort(void);               /* sort */
static int  GetFile(void);              /* read in file, set up ptrs */
static void PutFile(void);              /* write file by ptrs */
static int  CmprRecs(const void *elem1, const void *elem2);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      WinMain                                                         */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int PASCAL WinMain(HANDLE hInstance, HANDLE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
static char szAppName [] = "Jsrt";
HWND        hwnd;
MSG         msg;
WNDCLASS    wndclass;

/*      get cmd line params */

    _fstrcpy((char _far *)szCmdLine, lpszCmdLine);
    DoCmdLine();

/*      register class if first instance */

    if(!hPrevInstance){
        wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
        wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance;
        wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance, szAppName);
        wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wndclass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
        RegisterClass(&wndclass);}

/*      set up  */

    hwnd = CreateWindow(
           szAppName,                   /* window class name */
           "Jeff's Demo",               /* window caption */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,         /* window style */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,               /* initial x position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,               /* initial y position */
           210,                         /* initial x size */
           120,                         /* initial y size */
           NULL,                        /* parent window handle */
           NULL,                        /* window menu handle */
           hInstance,                   /* program instance handle */
           NULL);                       /* creation parameters */

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

/*      main msg loop */

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);}

    return msg.wParam;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      WndProc         main msg procedure                              */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
long FAR PASCAL _export WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam,
                                LONG lParam)
{
HDC         hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT        rect;

    switch (message){

      case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        DrawText(hdc, pszState[fState], -1, &rect,
         DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

        dwTicker = GetTickCount();      /* set delay for 3 secs */
        dwTicker += 3000ul;

        if(fState == SOKPARMS){
            fState = SSORT;
            DoSort();
            DrawText(hdc, pszState[fState], -1, &rect,
                     DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            dwTicker = GetTickCount();  /* set delay for 1 secs */
            dwTicker += 1000ul;}

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        while(dwTicker >= GetTickCount()){      /* do delay */
            ;}

        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0L);

        return 0;

      case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;}

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      DoCmdLine       get and check params                            */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void DoCmdLine(void)
{
    if(!szCmdLine[0]){                  /* exit if no parms */
        fState = SNOPARMS;
        return;}
    pszSrcName = szCmdLine;             /* set ptrs to src and dest */
    pszDstName = (BYTE *)memchr(szCmdLine, ' ', 80);
    if(!pszDstName){
        fState = SBADPARMS;
        return;}
    *pszDstName = 0;
    pszDstName++;

/*      open files */

    hfSrc = _lopen((char _far *)pszSrcName, READ);
    if(hfSrc == HFILE_ERROR){
        fState = SBADPARMS;
        return;}

    hfDst = _lcreat((char _far *)pszDstName, 0);
    if(hfDst == HFILE_ERROR){
        fState = SBADPARMS;
        _lclose(hfSrc);
        return;}

    fState = SOKPARMS;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      DoSort                                                          */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void DoSort(void)
{
    dwSrc = _llseek(hfSrc, 0ul, 2);     /* get size of source file */
    _llseek(hfSrc, 0ul, 0);

    hlMem = LocalAlloc(LPTR, 0x8000u);  /* get 32K for array of ptrs */
    if(!hlMem){
        return;}
    pLclBase = (BYTE *)hlMem;

    hgMem = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 0x100000ul); /* get 1MB for file image */
    if(!hgMem){
        return;}
    lpMemBase = GlobalLock(hgMem);

    GetFile();                          /* read the file */

/*                                      ** sort the data */
    qsort(pLclBase, wNumRec, sizeof(palpRec[0]), CmprRecs);

    PutFile();                          /* write the file */

    GlobalUnlock(hgMem);                /* release memory */
    GlobalFree(hgMem);
    LocalFree(hlMem);

    _lclose(hfSrc);                     /* close files */
    _lclose(hfDst);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      GetFile()                                                       */
/*                                                                      */
/*      Read file in at pMem+4 (keep on long boundary).                 */
/*      Prefix each record with byte count (replacing ENDLF),           */
/*      converting to p-string (cnt, data) format starting at pMem+3.   */
/*      Set uNumRec to # records in file.                               */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static int GetFile(void)
{
BYTE _far *lpCnt;                       /* ptr to record byte cnt */
BYTE _far *lpStr;                       /* ptr to record string */
BYTE _far *lpEnd;                       /* ptr to end of record */
BYTE _far *lpLast;                      /* ptr to end of last record */
BYTE _far *lpPrev;                      /* ptr to previous record */
WORD wCnt;                              /* record string size */

    palpRec = (BYTE _far **)pLclBase;   /* init ptr to ptrs */
    lpCnt   = (BYTE _far *)lpMemBase;   /* init ptr to first record */

    while(1){                           /* loop for each 64K chunk */
        lpStr   = lpCnt+4;              /* set ptr to 1st rec of chunk */
        cbSrc   = _lread(hfSrc, lpStr, CHUNKSZ); /* read data */
        if(!cbSrc)break;                /* stop if end file */
        lpLast  = lpStr+cbSrc;          /* add terminator to chunk */
        lpLast[0] = ENDLF;
        lpLast[1] = ENDLF;
        XP_SEG(lpCnt) += _AHINCR;}      /* bump ptr to next segment */

    lpCnt = (BYTE _far *)lpMemBase+2;   /* set up for record scan */
    while(1){                           /* loop for each 64K chunk */
        while(1){                       /* loop for each record */
            lpStr = lpCnt+2;            /* scan for ENDLF */
            lpEnd = (BYTE _far *)_fmemchr(lpStr, ENDLF, MAXRECSZ);
            if(!XP_OFF(lpEnd))return(1); /* exit if rec too big */
            wCnt = XP_OFF(lpEnd)-XP_OFF(lpStr); /* get count */
            if(!wCnt)break;             /* break if end of chunk */
            wCnt    -= 1;               /* adjust count */
            lpCnt[0] = (BYTE)(wCnt>>8); /* set count in bfr */
            lpCnt[1] = (BYTE)wCnt;
            *palpRec++ = lpCnt;         /* set ptr to record */
            wNumRec++;
            lpCnt += wCnt+2;}           /* advance ptr to next rec */

        if(lpEnd == lpLast)break;       /* break if done with file */
        XP_SEG(lpStr) += _AHINCR;       /* bump to next 64k block */
        XP_OFF(lpStr) = 4;
        if(*lpCnt != ENDCR){            /* if record spans 64k block */
            lpPrev = lpCnt+1;           /* set ptr to end prev rec */
            lpCnt = *--palpRec;         /* set ptr back to last rec */
            lpEnd = (BYTE _far *)_fmemchr(lpStr, ENDLF, MAXRECSZ);
            if(!XP_OFF(lpEnd))return(1); /* exit if rec too big */
            wCnt = XP_OFF(lpEnd)-XP_OFF(lpStr); /* get count */
            if(!wCnt)return(1);         /* exit if bad data */
            wCnt    -= 1;               /* adjust count */
            _fmemcpy(lpPrev, lpStr, wCnt); /* append data */
            lpPrev[wCnt] = 0;           /* add terminator to rec */
            wCnt += ((WORD)lpCnt[0]<<8)+((WORD)lpCnt[1])+1; /* append count */
            lpCnt[0] = (BYTE)(wCnt>>8); /* set count in bfr */
            lpCnt[1] = (BYTE)wCnt;
            *palpRec++ = lpCnt;         /* set ptr to record */
            lpCnt = lpEnd-1;}           /* set ptr to next count */
        else{
            lpCnt = lpStr-2;}}          /* set ptr to next count */
    *lpCnt = 0;                         /* add terminator to last rec */
    *palpRec = (BYTE _far *)0ul;        /* add terminator to ptr array */
    return(0);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      PutFile                                                         */
/*                                                                      */
/*      Write records from papRec array                                 */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void PutFile(void)
{
BYTE _far *lpCnt;                       /* ptr to record byte cnt */
BYTE _far *lpStr;                       /* ptr to record string */
WORD wCnt;                              /* record string size */

    palpRec = (BYTE _far **)pLclBase;   /* init ptr to ptrs */

    while(1){
        lpCnt = *palpRec++;             /* get next ptr */
        if(!(DWORD)lpCnt){
            break;}
        wCnt = ((WORD)lpCnt[0]<<8)+((WORD)lpCnt[1]); /* get count */
        lpStr = lpCnt+2;                /* set ptr to str */
        _lwrite(hfDst, lpStr, wCnt);    /* write str */
        _lwrite(hfDst, aucCRLF, 2);}    /* write ENDCR, ENDLF */
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*      CmprRecs(void *elem1, void *elem2)                              */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static int CmprRecs(const void *elem1, const void *elem2)
{
BYTE _far *pCmp1;                       /* ptr to rec 1 */
BYTE _far *pCmp2;                       /* ptr to rec 2 */
WORD wCnt;                              /* # bytes to compare */

    pCmp1 = *(BYTE _far **)elem1;       /* set ptrs */
    pCmp2 = *(BYTE _far **)elem2;

    wCnt = ((WORD)pCmp1[0]<<8)+pCmp1[1]+1;      /* get count */
/*                                              ** +1 for 'HI' */

    return(_fmemcmp(pCmp1+2, pCmp2+2, wCnt));   /* compare records */
}


@MissUnderstands - I didn't intend for those not interested to look through all of the code. It is a legacy retro-computing program example for the retro-computing community. There aren't very many Windows 3.1 286 protected mode code examples around anymore. This example shows a workaround for the fixed 64KB segment boundary issue.

I'd have preferred a simple code extract, possibly artificial, that clearly illustrated whatever point is being made about 286 protected mode programming.

@dave - Each function isn't that big. The key function is ReadFile(), which handles the issue that memory can only be accessed within 64KB segments, while text file records could span 64KB segments. The work-around was to read 63KB at a time, leaving room to merge a spanned record into a single record near the end of a 64 KB segment.

How long did what period last?

@cjs It's the duty of the person writing the question to leave out known-irrelevant details, because they only have to do it once. It's not the duty of answerers to determine which details are irrelevant, because they'd all have to do it separately.

I agree, neither the personal story nor the lengthy code has any relation to the question asked - in fact, it totally covers up what is asked - which is essentially just the second to last paragraph, neatly titles 'question'. Everything else has as much relation as talking about the weather back then. The way is will just deter future readers from gaining any benefit of question and answer.

@Raffzahn Could you try editing the question down, please? I would, but I'm hesitant to delete things I don't understand.

@wizzwizz4 -  the question is getting upvotes and has two answers also getting upvotes. Some here did want to see the complete code, and one here asked for the build files, so I made zip and provided a link.

@rcgldr Most questions around here get upvotes: that doesn't mean they can't be improved. Linking to the zip file is fine, but there are several problems with this question: "Update:" edits, the majority of the question being tangentially-relevant background (with the question proper tucked in the middle, not at the beginning or end), and a vague title. I suggest moving the information about this program to your personal website (and maybe elaborating on it), and then taking it all out of the question (ensuring that that the remaining question still stands on its own).

@rcgldr It's not too late to change anything about the question. (Three years later isn't too late!) That is a good reason to include code; but I'd suggest a paragraph explanation, possibly with a small code snippet, would be a better explanation than that full program: I didn't learn anything from reading the source code, and people who can read that code probably already know all about segments.

@wizzwizz4 -  I restored and cleaned up the title so that it matches my original intent. Since the title mentions example code, those not interested can ignore the code, and for those interested, the example code is there. If someone is searching for such an example, now that it's back in the title, it will be easier to find.

I think it was pretty strictly Windows 3.1 or maybe even 3.0 if you're talking 286.  I'm pretty sure 3.11 required 386.

@rcgldr getting up votes or answer isn't really a marker for quality. What is telling is that it gets so few up votes - despite even catching 'hot' status at some point. In addition it got an unusual amount of down votes. So if at all, it shows the question being not appreciated the way it is.

@wizzwizz4 I hesitate to edit, as I'm pretty sure it will be reverted. I'm not interested in edit games. Any serious minded edit would have to reduce it to the second half of the title "How long did Windows (which versions) support 80286 protected mode?" and a reformed content "80286 supported, like the 8086, a maximum segment size of 64 KiB. Unlike in 8086 real mode, 80286 protected mode did not allow arbitrary segment arithmetic. Applications were restricted to non continuous OS supplied segments of maximum 64 KiB. How long did Windows support programs using this 16 bit segment model."

@wizzwizz4 Neither the source code nor the lengthy rant about data splitting adds to the question asked, as that's a result of the memory model used. In fact, looking close, all of this can be reduced to a question about supported memory model.

@Raffzahn A reverted edit would still appear in the revision history, and could be used as a guide by future editors.

@davolfman -Windows 3.11 was a minor and free update to Windows 3.10. It could run on 286 or on 386. If on 386, it could run 386 enhanced mode. Perhaps you were thinking of Windows For Workgroups 3.11, which did require a 386, but I think it could still run 286 protected mode.

@Raffzahn - Some appreciate it, others don't. Some of those upvotes are probably from people that did want to see the example code, since the original and now edited title start with "example ... code" . The question has 1000+ views now. The example code is at the end of the question, so those not interested can just ignore the example code.

Is the question about the sample program or about 286 protected mode? Pick one.

There doesn't seem to be any sort of question about the code. It's just there.

Honestly, HNQ tourists will upvote just about anything that is not outright spam. I would not be drawing any inferences from the number of upvotes cast.

Unfortunately the way this program sets up _AHINCR is incorrect — the whole point of _AHINCR was to allow the operating environment to specify a different value without recompiling programs. It’s an external value, not a compile-time constant, and should be declared as extern int near _AHINCR;; see this MSJ article by Matt Pietrek. That way, the same program can run in real mode and protected mode on Windows, without recompilation.

@Raffzahn Getting well-upvoted answers may not be an indication of question quality, but it likely means that there's a good question in the idea that's not well stated. I've had plenty of questions on this SE that were initially not very well formed, but after seeing answers I was able to update the question to much better express what I was trying to get at. Sometimes you just need a few rounds of back-and-forth to refine things. And these questions should be kept on the site. If the core query one can perceive in in the question is bad, it will get closed through close votes, not downvotes.

@StephenKitt - Windows 3.10 or 3.11 on a 286 can only run in 286 protected mode (switching to real mode requires a reboot). I don't recall why I used a define for _AHINCR (maybe one of the compilers used that didn't have the external). If the code above is changed to  use extern int near _AHINCR;, JSRT.NMK compile line needs to be changed from -G2sw  to -GAs, otherwise _AHINCR will be an unresolved external. What I do recall is for Windows, _AHINCR was always 0x0008, for OS/2 1.0, always 0x0010. I don't recall what Xenix 286 used since I only wrote device drivers for it.

@cjs Too bad too few people seem to bother. Especially the asker here.

@rcgldr floppy patches like that were so rare I wasn't aware it existed. Yes I was thinking of WFW 3.11  I think I was also remembering the optional 386 support added around 3.1

@davolfman - we got win 3.11 on CD-ROM (1992). I have it on a later CD-ROM, 1997, Microsoft Developer - MS-DOS 6.22, Win 3.11, WFW 3.11, ... . The company had some 286 AT clones with custom I/O cards for data capture that was too fast for hard drives, so up to 16MB of ram was used to hold the data. Eventually got 386 clones, Windows NT, and used multi-threading, 1 thread for data capture, 3 or 4 threads for writing to files, each thread writing to a separate hard drive.

The first version of Windows to use 286 protected mode was Windows 3.0, released in 1990. Support for 286-based systems was dropped in version 3.11 for Workgroups in 1993, but support for software written for 16-bit protected mode Windows was only dropped in 64-bit versions of Windows, and software continued to be written for 16-bit Windows until after Windows 95 was released — while it was possible to write 32-bit software for Windows 3.1 (see below), 32-bit was the default only on Windows NT and 95 (and their successors).
As far as I’m aware, the first protected-mode operating system for the 80286 was Xenix in 1984. So looking at all PC operating environments, that’s the start of the 286 protected-mode “period”. As far as mainstream PC operating systems are concerned, the switch was slower — OS/2, designed for 286 protected mode, was released in 1987; as mentioned above, Windows only started using protected mode on 286s with Windows 3.0 in 1990 (after it started using protected mode on 386s!), and 286 DOS extenders were used in a limited number of applications such as 1-2-3 R3 (1989).
The last version of Xenix 286 was released in 1998. OS/2 dropped support for 286s in version 2.0 in 1992.
By late 1993, at least in the US and Western Europe, 286 PCs were no longer being sold (see also When did the 386 overtake the 286?), so it’s probably fair to say that the 286 protected-mode period started ending around then.
That overlaps with the other execution modes. Real mode started with the 8086/8088 (where it was the only execution mode), and operating environments using it continued to be developed throughout the 90s, with the last release of PC DOS happening in 1999 (embedded DOS lasted slightly longer). 32-bit protected mode in mainstream operating environments started being used in 1986 with Phar Lap’s 386|DOS-Extender and in 1987 with Windows/386, which used a 32-bit protected-mode kernel; end-user software running in 32-bit mode on Windows came later, starting with Watcom’s Win386 extender in 1991 and Microsoft’s own Win32s in 1992–93. Windows 3.0 included winmem32 in 1990 but that wasn’t a full-blown extender.
Support for 16-bit protected-mode software is another story — current Linux systems can still run 16-bit Windows software using Wine, and 32-bit editions of Windows supports such software natively.

A 10-year run isn't bad ...

I have fond memories of being loaned out for drivers on Xenix at SCO around 1988-1989. The development group was on the second floor above a free clinic. The couch was a repository for hard copy printouts. One of the programmers had a captains chair from a Dodge Van as his seat. A window allowed access to the roof with lawn chairs for breaks. One of the clinic people lived in a yellow school bus with a draped American flag as a door, in the parking lot. Tuesday nights were single ticket nights at the boardwalk, mostly for the Giant Dipper (sister to San Diego roller coaster with same name).

@davidbak roundabout 10 year is about what most technologies can expect as mainstream lifetime. Total life time may be longer. The 80286 being used in systems from 1980 until ca. 2000 might be longer, but as a PC base it started in 1984 and was gone already around 1990 - though software of course supported it a few more years because of it's installed base. More so anything tied to a specific hardware rarely gets mainstream support past ~10 years. No matter if 80286, C64 or UMTS :)

Watcom 10 C|C++ included winmem32 as one of it's build model types (tiny, small, ..., winmem32),, which made it very popular for a while.  Windows 3.10 + 3.11 came with winmem32, while win32s (a subset of Windows NT API) was an optional add on.

While Minix was always a niche operating system, it gained somewhat wide use in teaching and hobbyist circles. Especially as Linux required 386 processors, while Minix ran on the cheaper 286.
From Minix 1.5 release announcement (1991):
3.1 ADDITIONAL MINIX 1.5 FEATURES (IBM VERSION):
  - Runs in protected mode on 286 and 386
  - Support for extended memory up to 16M on 286 and 386
  - Up to 3 simultaneous users on one machine
  - RS-232 serial line support with terminal emulation, kermit, zmodem, etc.
  - Distributed computing on Ethernet (remote login, etc.)

Anecdotally, I myself used Minix to begin learning about POSIX-style operating systems in late 1990s.
(This answer was written before the question was clarified to be Windows-specific.)

Side note: MINIX is also used in the Intel "Management Engine", a separate core in most modern Intel chips that's responsible for security. See Ever Heard of MINIX? It’s The World’s Most Widely Used Operating System.
